# catch textFieldDidEndEditing of UITextField runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, objective-c-runtime

I am using objective C aspect library, in below case I want to listen to all the UITextfields when the textFieldDidEndEditing method is called.

It's not working, I tried for UIButton it works but not for UITextfield and UITextview.

```
 [UITextField aspect_hookSelector:@selector(textFieldDidEndEditing:) withOptions:AspectPositionAfter usingBlock:^(id<AspectInfo> aspectInfo) {

        if ([[aspectInfo instance] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *textView = [aspectInfo instance];

            NSLog(@"***** UITEXTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT click event called ");

        }
    }
```

what am I missing in this case ? why will it not work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure how that library works but it looks like you are trying to listen for a `textFieldDidEndEditing:` call. The problem is that that method doesn't get called on `UITextField`. It gets called on a `UITextFieldDelegate`.

If you want to listen for `textFieldDidEndEditing:` on any number of textfields you can just use the built in Notification system and subscribe to the `UITextFieldTextDidEndEditing` notification.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification.name/1619633-uitextfieldtextdidendediting)